# OL3 Z-index cluster fetures

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Warning: Google translator:
how to make the cluster display on top simple features

http://jsfiddle.net/3dv1wdho/16/

[image]

it is necessary that the cluster was on top

```
    var count = 20000;
var features = new Array(count);
var e = 4500000;
for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  var coordinates = [2 * e * Math.random() - e, 2 * e * Math.random() - e];
  features[i] = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates));
}

var source = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: features
});

var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
  distance: 40,
  source: source
});

var styleCache = {};
var defaultStyle = [new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                        anchor: [0.7, 47],  
                        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                        src: 'http://tennisterin.com/images/gmap/maps-point.png'
                    }))
})];
var threshold = 1;
var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: clusterSource,
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    var size = feature.get('features').length;
    if (size > threshold) {
      var style = styleCache[size];
      if (!style) {
        style = [new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 10,
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: '#fff'
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: '#3399CC'
            })
          }),
          text: new ol.style.Text({
            text: size.toString(),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: '#fff'
            })
          })
        })];
        styleCache[size] = style;
      }
    } else {
      return defaultStyle;
    }
    return style;
  }
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
});

var raw = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, clusters],
  renderer: 'canvas',
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

with increasing green icon is superimposed on top of the cluster, it is necessary on the contrary to the cluster was on top of a green icons.
how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `zIndex` property to your `defaultStyle`:

```
var defaultStyle = [
    new ol.style.Style({
        zIndex: -1000,
        ...
    })];
```